# At the enemies or at the enemy

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> The French used this tactic at the enemy.
>
> This tank as a special machine gun that fires 1000 round/s at the
>   enemy.

Should we use the plural "enemies" or is "enemy" fine? Why is that?

Comment: 1000 rounds/second? really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a particular war, singular "enemy" is correct.
 The plural form "enemies" might be used if talking about the use of the tactic or the weapon against various other nations in multiple wars.

The preposition should be "The French used this tactic **against** the enemy."
The preposition "at" is correct in "...gun that fires 1000 rounds/s **at** the enemy."